# Action Script 3. How to get data from swf (as) to php and write to database

Tags: php, database, facebook, actionscript-3

I'm creating Flash "memory" game, Idea to discover 2 equal cards. Here is timer which count time in how many seconds all cards are discovered. After complete game timer stops. How can I get this time from swf file and write to database? As I understand I need take this data with php file, but don't have idea how to do It.

As I know I need to do something like that:

```
        var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, scoreSaveResponse,false,0,true);
        var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://mysite.com/score.php");
        var urlVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
            urlVars.time = timer.currentCount;
            urlVars.userName = "yourUserName";

        request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
        urlLoader.data = urlVars;
        urlLoader.load(request);

function scoreSaveResponse(e:Event):void {
    //whatever you return from the php page is found in urlLoader.data
}

//LondonDrugs_MediaServices's code
```

But could someone explain me how to do It, because If I use this part of code nothing happens, I don't get any errors, but I don't know how to use this in php or how to write it to database.

My app will be used for Facebook, that's mean username will be used the same as in Facebook. So I think first i need to get time to PHP than get username from Facebook and write both to database.

Thank you for answers.

Comment: How you do this depends on what kind of database you're using.  This question is a little involved for Stackoverflow (in my opinion), what you really need is a tutorial.    This came up for me in a quick google search: http://www.freewebmasterhelp.com/tutorials/phpmysql

Comment: I will use MySql. I need just a little information about It. How to use AS with PHP. This tutorial which you gave is how to use PHP and MySQL, but I need some info how to use It with AS. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use AMFPHP.
AMFPHP makes it possible to write a service for your application where you can store your SWF values into a PHP database.

http://www.silexlabs.org/amfphp/